# Using g++ 4.6.1 I get many C++ compile errors when trying to include xaudio2.h

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

I have a c++ Windows app that compiles fine using Visual Studio 2010. I also wanted to have the ability to compile it using MinGW (on a Windows7-64 PC). When g++ processes the xaudio2.h header file I get the errors listed below. Does anyone know of a fix aside from manually hacking the include file.

```
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:51:1: error: pasting "5a508685" and "-" does not give
a valid preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:51:1: error: pasting "-" and "a254" does not give a va
lid preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:51:1: error: pasting "a254" and "-" does not give a va
lid preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:51:1: error: pasting "-" and "4fba" does not give a va
lid preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:51:1: error: pasting "4fba" and "-" does not give a va
lid preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:51:1: error: pasting "-" and "9b" does not give a vali
d preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:51:1: error: pasting "9b82" and "-" does not give a va
lid preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:51:1: error: pasting "-" and "9a" does not give a vali
d preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:52:1: error: pasting "db05ea35" and "-" does not give
a valid preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:52:1: error: pasting "-" and "0329" does not give a va
lid preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:52:1: error: pasting "0329" and "-" does not give a va
lid preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:52:1: error: pasting "-" and "4d4b" does not give a va
lid preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:52:1: error: pasting "4d4b" and "-" does not give a va
lid preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:52:1: error: pasting "-" and "a5" does not give a vali
d preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:52:1: error: pasting "a53a" and "-" does not give a va
lid preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:52:1: error: pasting "-" and "6d" does not give a vali
d preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:53:1: error: pasting "8bcf1f58" and "-" does not give
a valid preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:53:1: error: pasting "-" and "9fe7" does not give a va
lid preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:53:1: error: pasting "9fe7" and "-" does not give a va
lid preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:53:1: error: pasting "-" and "4583" does not give a va
lid preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:53:1: error: pasting "4583" and "-" does not give a va
lid preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:53:1: error: pasting "-" and "8a" does not give a vali
d preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:53:1: error: pasting "8ac6" and "-" does not give a va
lid preprocessing token
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:53:1: error: pasting "-" and "e2" does not give a vali
d preprocessing token
In file included from common/system.h:71:0,
                 from game.cpp:1:
SDKS/DX/Include/xaudio2.h:65:69: fatal error: sal.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Here are the lines in the xaudio2.h:

```
DEFINE_CLSID(XAudio2, 5a508685, a254, 4fba, 9b, 82, 9a, 24, b0, 03, 06, af);
DEFINE_CLSID(XAudio2_Debug, db05ea35, 0329, 4d4b, a5, 3a, 6d, ea, d0, 3d, 38, 52);
DEFINE_IID(IXAudio2, 8bcf1f58, 9fe7, 4583, 8a, c6, e2, ad, c4, 65, c8, bb);
```

and it looks like the defines are in comdecl.h as:

```
#define DEFINE_CLSID(className, l, w1, w2, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8) \
            class DECLSPEC_UUID_WRAPPER(l##-##w1##-##w2##-##b1##b2##-##b3##b4##b5##b6##b7##b8) className; \
            EXTERN_C const GUID CLSID_##className

#define DEFINE_IID(interfaceName, l, w1, w2, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8) \
            interface DECLSPEC_UUID_WRAPPER(l##-##w1##-##w2##-##b1##b2##-##b3##b4##b5##b6##b7##b8) interfaceName; \
            EXTERN_C const GUID IID_##interfaceName
```

Comment: What does that line of the include file *look* like?

Comment: I added the lines to the question.

Comment: It's trying to generate preprocessor tokens containing `-` characters, which are not valid. Presumably Microsoft C++ supports this as one of its many extensions. Unfortunately, it's very unlikely you'll get this through a standard preprocessor without hacking it.

Answer (score 1):

Found a trick that works. include XAudio2 as if from C, not C++.

```
#undef __cplusplus
#include <xaudio2.h>
#define __cplusplus
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help to explain it [GCC Concatenation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) .